# Linux - Sending a command to a screen through a shell script?

Tags: scripting, shell, gnu-screen

I'm trying to figure out how to make a script that will be able to send commands to a screen that will execute within whatever the screen is doing. Is this possible, and if so, how is it done? I've already tried screen -X etc, and it is not executing the commands.

Comment: I don't think you can do this once the screen is already running.  What do you suppose might happen if a program (other than the shell) is already running and accepting input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it depends on the commands you need to execute:
If you need to execute commands in an existing screen session, you need to re-attach and execute the commands using this command line:

```
screen -r -S "<screenName>" "command/or/script/to/execute"
```

If want to execute the commands inside of a new screen session, you can use this:

```
screen -A -m -d -S "<screenName>" "command/or/script/to/execute"
```

You can read more about some common screen commands here: [10 Screen Command Examples to Manage Linux Terminals](http://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/)

Comment: It sounds as though `screen -X` is what the questioner really wants, but for some reason it's not working for him.  That is, he wants to run a command in an existing screen session without having to attach to it.

Comment: Wouldn't putting the command in graves like that cause the local shell to interpret it in the calling shell and paste its output as arguments to screen?

Comment: `screen -dmS <screename> <commandToRun>` worked for me